# Using Vuex, how do I remove items from an array when they are part of an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

Referencing the live demo code here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-r26tg

Let's say I have a Vuex store with the following data:

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    categories: [
      {
        name: "Category A",
        items: [{ name: "Item 1" }, { name: "Item 2" }, { name: "Item 3" }]
      },
      {
        name: "Category B",
        items: [{ name: "Item A" }, { name: "Item B" }, { name: "Item C" }]
      },
      {
        name: "Category C",
        items: [{ name: "Item !" }, { name: "Item @" }, { name: "Item #" }]
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

And I have an `App.vue`, `Category.vue` and `Item.vue` that are set up so that they are rendered like so:

```
//App.vue
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Category v-for="(category, index) in categories" :category="category" :key="index"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    components: { Category },

    computed: {
      ...mapState(["categories"])
    }
  };
</script>
```

```
//Category.vue
<template>
  <div class="category">
    <div class="header">{{ category.name }}</div>
    <Item v-for="(item, index) in category.items" :item="item" :key="index"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    components: { Item },

    props: {
      category: { type: Object, required: true }
    }
  };
</script>
```

```
//Item.vue
<template>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="name">{{ item.name }}</div>
    <div class="delete" @click="onDelete">&#10006;</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      item: { type: Object, required: true }
    },

    methods: {
      onDelete() {
        this.$store.commit("deleteItem", this.item);
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

In other words, `App.vue` gets the list of categories from Vuex, then passes it down to `Category.vue` as a prop for each category, then `Category.vue` passes down `category.items` to `Item.vue` as a prop for each item.

I need to delete an item when the delete button next to it is clicked:

[image]

However, at the `Item.vue` level, I only have access to the `item`, but not the `category`. If I send the `item` to Vuex, I have no way of telling which `category` it belongs to. How do I get a reference to the `category` so that I can delete the item from it using Vuex?

I can think of two ways:

1. Add a parent reference back to the `category` for each `item`. This is undesirable not only because I'd have to massage the `item` data, but also because it introduces a circular reference that I'd rather not have to deal with in other parts of the app.
2. Emit an event from `Item.vue` up to `Category.vue` and let `Category.vue` handle the Vuex call for deletion. This way the category and the to-be-deleted item are both known.

Is there a better way of handling this kind of deletion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd strongly recommend (2). In general, if you can create a component which takes props and emits events without having other side effects (API calls, Vuex mutations, etc.) that's usually the correct path. In this case, you can probably even push the event all the way back to the parent's parent.

Where shared state (Vuex) **really** helps is when you have two or more components which are far away from each other in the DOM tree. E.g. imagine a header with a count of the total items. That degree of spatial separation may exist in your app, but it doesn't in this simple example.

An additional benefit to emitting an event here is that you care more easily use tools like [storybook](https://storybook.js.org/) without having to deal with any Vuex workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd go with 2 (emit an event from `Item.vue` up to `Category.vue`), but, since you asked about possibilities, there is a third way: *passing a **callback function***.

Example:

`Category.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div class="category">
    <div class="header">{{ category.name }}</div>
    <Item v-for="(item, index) in category.items" :item="item" :key="index"
     :on-delete="deleteItem"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// ...
export default {
  // ...
  methods: {
    deleteItem(i) {
      console.log('cat', this.category.name, 'item', i)
      //this.$store.commit("deleteItem", this.item);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

`Item.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="name">{{ item.name }}</div>
    <div class="delete" @click="() => onDelete(this.item)">&#10006;</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    item: { type: Object, required: true },
    onDelete: { type: Function }
  },
};
</script>
```

[Updated sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-jrxcw). Notice, in this case, the callback is `onDelete`.

If this were React, the callback was for sure a more idiomatic way. In Vue, as said, I'd argue in favor of emitting the **event** in the child and handling it in the parent (with `v-on`).

Comment: Of course, you can also declare, in `Category.vue`: `:on-delete="deleteItem(item)"`, which makes it even closer to what the event option would be.